# How to update global value after onchange call?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, global-variables

I run this function on a button click. Everytime I change smth and I store the value on a, I want it to store everytime on the global variable. But it doesnt.

```
function ChangeStuff() {
var localVariable;
$("#loc").change(function() {

  $("select option:selected").each(function() {

    Selected = $("#loc").find("option:selected").text();
  });

  arr.forEach(function(locItem) {
    if (Selected === locItem.s) {
      Selected1 = locItem._id;
    }

  });
  a = Selected1;
  //inside here shows correctly
  console.log(a);
  //apple //banana according to what i chose
}).change(); 
         }
     //here the global variable a is still 0;
       console.log(a);
       //0

 //i press continue to fire the function
//so everytime it changes I want it to update
```

this is where i fire the function

```
    <button  data-ver="1" id="Continue" onclick="ChangeStuf();">Continue</button>

       <select class="wide-control form-control default" id="locations" >
       <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
          </select>
```

when i assign the function onchange-"" on the select it gives me an infinite loop  https://jsfiddle.net/x3s8pyam/1/

Comment: `Selected1 = a;` is not the same as doing `a = Selected1;` Nothing shown would ever change value of `a`

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to fix it like that and it still shows 0

Comment: We don't know what `arr` is. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: We also don't know if or where you call `ChangeStuff()` or if anything is selected when this code runs

Comment: What do you mean by "*here the global variable a is still 0;*"? Where is that "here" exactly? Could it be that this part of the code is simply executed before anything did change (and before your update code ran)?

Comment: @Bergi it means when I console the "a" variable inside the .change it updates correctly, Everytime I change the select element it changes also. 
Outside, it always shows 0 if i console it. 
I want it to update the same way as it does inside

Comment: Too many unknowns without a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide the full code including the call to `ChangeStuff` and the "outside" part.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x3s8pyam/1/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reassigning a new value to `a` at any point in the function. So, it's not going to change.

Think of `a = selected1;` as reading like "a 'is assigned' Selected1". And `Selected1 = a;` as the vice versa. That helps me :)